# Spring Boot Data JPA and PostgreSQL Auto Generate Enum Type

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

If I use MySQL, my entities and enums are created successfully.

I changed my db as PostgreSQL-9.4 . So, I have some errors as follow:

> ... Caused by:
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: **Unable to
> execute schema management to JDBC target [create table role (id int8
> not null, name enum('ADMIN', 'USER', 'SEARCH') not null, primary key
> (id))]**  at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:236)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:167)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
> ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  ... 22
> common frames omitted
>
> **Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
> ERROR: type "enum" does not exist**   Position: 43    at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:303)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:289)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:266)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:246)
> ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
> ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]  at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   ... 32 common frames
> omitted

My Enum:

```
public enum RoleType {

    ADMIN("ADMIN"),

    SEARCH("SEARCH"),

    USER("USER");

    private final String value;

    RoleType(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

My Role Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "enum('ADMIN', 'USER', 'SEARCH')")
    private RoleType name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> users;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(RoleType name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public RoleType getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(RoleType name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

My application.yml file for postgresql:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: username
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

My old application.yml file for mysql:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: user
    password: password
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency-->
        
    </dependencies>
```

How can I configure it to auto generate enum types?

Comment: You said Postgres, but then you're using MySQL configuration everywhere.

Comment: @chrylis I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

To use DB enums PostgreSQL is different from MySQL.

Read more about how to create an enum in PostgreSQL here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-enum.html

This means that you cannot create the enum using JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: If you're talking about mysql dependency in pom file , I've set that part as a comment line.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @simon-martinelli

Answer (score -1):

The "enum(...)" is used for mysql. I removed the line and the problem is fixed.

> @Column(columnDefinition = "enum('ADMIN', 'USER', 'SEARCH')")

However, the [open-source](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) hibernate-types project allows you to map database-specific columns. We are going to see from [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/12/map-postgresql-jpa-entity-hibernate.html) and [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) how you can map a PostgreSQL Enum type to a Java array when using JPA and Hibernate. But I'm not sure how to use this with spring boot.